# For a sublinear functional $p$ on $X$, $|p(x)-p(y)|\leq p(x-y)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a linear space and $p:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a sublinear functional, then by definition

(a) $p(x+y)\leq p(x)+p(y)$

(b) $p(ax)=|a|p(x)$

for every $x,y \in X$ and scalar $a$

My question is how to prove 
$$|p(x)-p(y)|\leq p(x-y)$$

This is edited now for correction in statement

Thankyou

Comment: Also, you should edit in your attempts or thoughts in the post, or you risk your question getting deleted and potentially closed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the relation you seek to prove does not hold in general.

For example, let $X = \mathbb{R}$, and let $p(x) = \lvert x \rvert$. Then of course we have 
$$
p(x+ y) = \big\lvert x+y \big\rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert = p(x) + p(y)
$$
for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, and also
$$
p(\alpha x) = \big\lvert \alpha x \big\rvert = \lvert \alpha \rvert \, \lvert x \rvert = \lvert \alpha \rvert \, p(x)
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and (real) scalars $\alpha$.

However, there exist $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ for which
$$
p(x-y) \not\leq p(x) - p(y).
$$
For example, let us put $x = 1$ and $y = 2$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, you want to show that $$p(y)-p(x-y)\leq p(x)\leq p(y)+p(x-y).$$ Observe that 
$$p(x)=p(x-y+y)\leq p(x-y)+p(y),$$ which gives one side. The other bound is the same as wanting to show $$p(y)\leq p(x-y)+p(x).$$ This follows similarly: $$p(y)=p(y-x+x)\leq p(x)+p(y-x)=p(x)+p(-(x-y))=p(x)+p(x-y).$$